# Error parsing JSON from Tag-Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm passing an json object to my js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/main.js">
  { lang: 'de' }
</script>
```

Trying to get the json object in main.js:

```
var scriptContent = $('script').filter(function () { return this.src.match(/js\/main\.js/g); }).html(),
  params = $.parseJSON( scriptContent.replace(/&quot;/g, '"') );
```

But this results in the following error: `JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

As you can see I already tried replacing `&quot;` by `"`

I tried `{ lang: "de" }` instead of `{ lang: 'de' }`

How to get this working?

Comment: That's not JSON. http://json.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet is incorrect JSON. Property keys have to be quoted too.

To quickly produce valid JSON (for testing purposes?), use [`JSON.stringify( some_object )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), eg:

```
JSON.stringify({ lang: "de" });
>>> {"lang":"de"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Properties in JSON should be surrounded by quotes, like this:

```
{
    "lang": "de"
}
```

Also, to test if a JSON piece is valid you should use http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON object

```
{
    "lang": "de"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add also :

```
scriptContent = scriptContent.replace(/\n/g, '');
```

to remove brak-lines